# GitHub Repository Rest API: How to find files matching a pattern?

Tags: github

I'm trying to write an automation job that will find all `*.md` files in a repository with lots of nested markdown files. I'm struggling to find the right API for this. The closest I found is the Search API, but it seems to return a lot of junk.

The closest I found is accessing

`https://${githubUrl}/${githubRepoName}/tree-list/${githubCommmit}`

which returns

```
{
  "paths": [...filepaths...],
}
```

but it lists ALL of the files in the repository, which is a lot.